How to impl FindAuthor<H160> with Babe
I want add pallet-evm in my substrate node. and my substrate node use Babe instead of Aura. How can I Impl FindAuthor whih Babe ?
this is the example of Aura. I want to impl it with Babe
pub struct FindAuthorTruncated<F>(PhantomData<F>);
impl<F: FindAuthor<u32>> FindAuthor<H160> for FindAuthorTruncated<F> {
    fn find_author<'a, I>(digests: I) -> Option<H160>
    where
        I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item = (ConsensusEngineId, &'a [u8])>,
    {
        if let Some(author_index) = F::find_author(digests) {
            let authority_id = Aura
::authorities()[author_index as usi
ze].clone();
            return Some(H160::from_slice(&authority_id.to_raw_vec()[4..24]))
        }
        None
    }
}


There is not that much difference. Basically you just need to replace Aura with Babe.
pub struct FindAuthorTruncated<F>(PhantomData<F>);
impl<F: FindAuthor<u32>> FindAuthor<H160> for FindAuthorTruncated<F> {
    fn find_author<'a, I>(digests: I) -> Option<H160>
    where
        I: 'a + IntoIterator<Item = (ConsensusEngineId, &'a [u8])>,
    {
        let author_index = F::find_author(digests)?;

        let authority_id = Babe
::authorities()[author_index as usi
ze].clone();
        Some(H160::from_slice(&authority_id.to_raw_vec()[4..24]))
    }
}


H160::from_slice(&(authority_id.0).to_raw_vec()[4..24]) Should be this
